# Запись в БД SQL без перезагрузки страницы PHP, jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery

Как сделать запись в БД SQL без перезагрузки страницы? И чтобы сразу обновлялся p class="name". Пока что запись создается, но страница перезагружается.

Есть такой код:

```
<p class="name"><?php echo $order['name']; ?> // вывожу название заказа из БД. Должен обновляться

<input class="id" type="text" value="<?php echo $order['id']; ?>"> // ввод id
<input class="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $order['name']; ?>"> // ввод name
<button class="submit">Изменить</button>
```

Есть jQuery скрипт, обрабатывающий эту форму:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button.submit').on('click', function(){
var id = $('input.id').val();
var name = $('input.name').val();
// отправить данные в update-name-order.php
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: "update-name-order.php",
data: { id: id, name: name }
})
.done(function() {

});
})
})
```

Есть файл update-name-order.php

```
<?php
$id = $_POST ['id'];
$name = $_POST ['name'];

mysqli_query ($connection, "UPDATE `order_list` SET `name` = '$name' WHERE `order_list`.`id` = '$id'");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно сделать форме или кнопке(остального кода не видно) preventDefault что бы по клику кнопки она не отправлялась, а добавлять стили просто дописать в ajax

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    success: function() {
      если успешно выполнился запрос то добавить класс чему угодно
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что куда добавить :) есть кнопка <button class="submit">Изменить</button> и как ей добавить этот preventDefault?

Comment: $('button.submit').on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault()
Но в вашем случае обработчик на форму повесить мб стоит

Comment: Допустим, теперь записи делаются без перезагрузки. А как сделать, чтобы <p class="name"> обновлялся новым значением? То есть мне не class нужно обновлять, а значение <p>

Comment: @АлександрЗинченко в функции `done` `$('.name').text(name);`

Comment: @AntonMironov, не помогло, к сожалению, либо я не туда вставил